# Qt - Custom Window title bar

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to implement a custom window frame in my application and have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time. And everywhere I searched, it was only said about the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag and that you need to implement the functions of moving and resizing the window yourself. But I need to have other functions like window binding and win + arrow key combinations (if we are talking about windows).

I have come across the `startSystemMove()` and `startSystemResize()` functions but they don't work properly with the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` flags.
A good example for an application that has all these features is Telegram Desktop which also uses Qt.

Comment: What the toolkit doesn't provide out of the box, one usually has to implement oneself (often using lower level APIs)...

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, only in this case the question is: how to do it?

Comment: Start by adding a basic `QWidget` based title bar to your widget hierarchy and then think about how you want to use mouse/keyboard events to perform the various function you require.